# Como contar ocorrência de strings dentro de um dicionário formado por listas no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

Eu tenho um dicionário de pesquisa de satisfação que o avaliador pode avaliar até 6 produtos. O programa armazena o avaliador, o refrigerante e a nota para o refrigerante.

E eu tenho que mostrar o nome dos avaliadores e a **quantidade de produtos que estes avaliaram individualmente**.

```
pesquisa = {'PEDRO': ['FANTA',5,'PEPSI',4],'ANA': ['SPRITE',5,'COCACOLA,4]}

def relatorio_avaliadores():
    print('Relatório de Avaliadores')

    for nome in sorted(pesquisa.keys()):
        
    print(f'{nome} avaliou o total de, , produto(s).')
```

Como posso contar o número de refrigerantes que foi avaliado por cada pessoa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falando especificamente da [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474516/112052), [`len` já retorna um número inteiro](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), então fazer `int(len(etc...))` é redundante e desnecessário. Fazer apenas `count = len(pesquisa[nome]) // 2` seria o suficiente (usando o operador de divisão inteira `//` para que o resultado não seja um `float`).

Mas na verdade dividir por 2 me parece um pouco de "gambiarra", para contornar o fato de que você está usando uma lista, que não parece ser a estrutura mais adequada para este caso. Se a ideia é ter uma nota para cada refrigerante, acho melhor usar um dicionário que mapeia o nome de cada refrigerante com sua respectiva nota. Pode parecer um detalhe bobo ("*ah, mas com listas funciona*"), mas [escolher a estrutura de dados adequada é meio caminho andado para um código melhor](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/163185).

Sendo assim, eu faria desta forma:

```
def relatorio_avaliadores(pesquisa):
    print('Relatório de Avaliadores')
    for nome in sorted(pesquisa):
        print(f'{nome} avaliou o total de {len(pesquisa[nome])} produto(s).')

# as notas ficam em outro dicionário
pesquisa = {
  'PEDRO': { 'FANTA': 5, 'PEPSI': 4 }, # cada refrigerante é mapeado para sua nota
  'ANA': { 'SPRITE': 5, 'COCACOLA': 4 }
}

relatorio_avaliadores(pesquisa)
```

Repare que para ordenar as chaves, posso fazer simplesmente `sorted(pesquisa)`. E se eu só quero imprimir a quantidade e não vou usar este valor para mais nada, nem precisaria da variável `cont`.

E agora não preciso mais dividir por 2, pois [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping), o `len` de um dicionário retorna a quantidade de chaves deste, e como cada chave corresponde a um refrigerante avaliado pela pessoa, ao usar `len(pesquisa[nome])` já terei o valor correto.

Outro detalhe é que da forma que você fez, a função `relatorio_avaliadores` só funcionava para o dicionário `pesquisa` criado fora dela. Mas agora eu mudei a função para receber o dicionário como parâmetro, assim ela funciona para qualquer outro dicionário que tenha a mesma estrutura. Ex:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def relatorio_avaliadores(pesquisa):
    print('Relatório de Avaliadores')
    # apenas para mostrar outra forma de iterar pelo dicionário
    for nome, notas in sorted(pesquisa.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
        print(f'{nome} avaliou o total de {len(notas)} produto(s).')

# dados de uma pesquisa
pesquisa1 = {
  'PEDRO': { 'FANTA': 5, 'PEPSI': 4 },
  'ANA': { 'SPRITE': 5, 'COCACOLA': 4 }
}
relatorio_avaliadores(pesquisa1)

# dados de outra pesquisa
pesquisa2 = {
  'Fulano': { 'FANTA': 5, 'PEPSI': 4 },
  'Ciclano': { 'SPRITE': 5, 'COCACOLA': 4, 'TUBAÍNA': 5 },
  'Beltrano': {},
  'Trajano': { 'GUARANÁ': 3, 'FANTA': 2, 'PEPSI': 1, 'COCACOLA': 4 }
}
relatorio_avaliadores(pesquisa2)

# posso inclusive passar o dicionário diretamente
relatorio_avaliadores({
  'Maria': { 'FANTA': 3 },
  'José': { 'COCACOLA': 5, 'SPRITE': 2 },
  'Fulano': { 'GUARANÁ': 4, 'PEPSI': 2, 'COCACOLA': 4 }
})
```

Repare que eu posso passar qualquer dicionário para a função, e ela funciona da mesma forma (assim ela fica mais genérica, em vez de depender de uma variável externa à ela).

Também mostrei outra forma de iterar pelo dicionário, retornando ao mesmo tempo o nome e as notas, e ordenando pela chave: [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) retorna as chaves e valores em tuplas, e na ordenação eu digo para usar o primeiro elemento da tupla, que é a chave do dicionário (uso [`itemgetter(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) para indicar que vou usar o primeiro elemento - lembre-se que os índices começam em zero, por isso usei `itemgetter(0)`).

---

E como lembrado nos comentários, se você não tem controle sobre a estrutura, pode converter sua estrutura inicial para a que sugeri acima:

```
pesquisa = {'PEDRO': ['FANTA',5,'PEPSI',4],'ANA': ['SPRITE',5,'COCACOLA',4]}
pesquisa = { nome: dict(zip(notas[::2], notas[1::2])) for nome, notas in pesquisa.items() }
```

Ou seja, para cada avaliador, eu pego a lista de notas e transformo no dicionário. O truque é usar os *slices* `[::2]` (pega os índices pares da lista) e `[1::2]` (pega os índices ímpares). [Leia aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) para entender melhor como funciona esta sintaxe.

Comment: Vale a pena dizer como converter em `dict`, já que não sabemos se está no controle do AP, qualquer coisa como: `d = {i: dict(zip(pesquisa[i][::2], pesquisa[i][1::2])) for i in pesquisa}`

Comment: @Miguel Boa, atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

Comment: De nada @hkotsubo (:

Answer (score 2):

Se for sempre esse o formato das contagens também podes assim:

```
pesquisa = {'PEDRO': ['FANTA',5,'PEPSI',4],'ANA': ['SPRITE',5,'COCACOLA',4], 'DIEGO': ['INTEL', 7, 'PYTHON', 8, 'WINDOWS', 9, 'LINUX', 10]}
c = {i: sum((1 for j in pesquisa[i][::2])) for i in pesquisa}
print(c) # {'PEDRO': 2, 'DIEGO': 4, 'ANA': 2}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/SaddlebrownOutgoingKey#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver! Sou iniciante e ainda uso coisas básicas para resolver meus problemas, se souberem de uma forma mais pytonica eu aceito sugestões!

```
def relatorio_avaliadores():
    print('Relatório de Avaliadores')

    for nome in sorted(pesquisa.keys()):
        count = int(len(pesquisa[nome])/2)
        
        print(f'{nome} avaliou o total de, {count}, produto(s).')
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso não queira dividir por 2, como fez aqui:

> ```
> pesquisa = {'PEDRO': ['FANTA',5,'PEPSI',4],'ANA': ['SPRITE',5,'COCACOLA',4]}
>
> def relatorio_avaliadores():
>     print('Relatório de Avaliadores')
>
>     for nome in sorted(pesquisa.keys()):
>         count = int(len(pesquisa[nome])/2)
>         
>         print(f'{nome} avaliou o total de, {count}, produto(s).')
> ```

Você pode iterar utilizando list comprehension e ver quais são do tipo str com o isinstance:

```
pesquisa = {'PEDRO': ['FANTA',5,'PEPSI',4],'ANA': ['SPRITE',5,'COCACOLA',4]}

def relatorio_avaliadores():
    print('Relatório de Avaliadores')

    for nome, avaliacoes in sorted(pesquisa.items()):
        count = len([i for i in avaliacoes if isinstance(i, str)])
        print(f'{nome} avaliou o total de, {count} produto(s).')
```

Pode fazer com o filter também:

```
count = len(list(filter(lambda x : isinstance(x, str), avaliacoes)))
```

Dessa forma só irá contar quando encontrar algo no formato 'string'.